# FirebaseAnimatedList query returns a blank list

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I currently am trying to build a FirebaseAnimatedList that returns data from Realtime Database. It does return data but it does not returning some specific data when I put a query.

I have a database `subjects` that holds multiple variables like course name, teacher name etc. There is also a variable, department, that shows which type of department the subject is categorized under. And I want FirebaseAnimatedList to return data whose department variable is equal to the department of whichever user is currently logged into the app.

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
  query: subjectref.orderByChild('department').equalTo(currentworker.department),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,Animation<double> animation, int index) {
        return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.value['courseName']),
        );
      }
)
```

```
User? wuser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
Worker currentworker = Worker();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("employees")
        .doc(wuser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      this.currentworker = Worker.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Above are my codes for FirebaseAnimatedList and the returning current logged in user's details from Firestore. And my results, I get a blank page returned. However, if I do write the value of department name directly like `subjectref.orderByChild('department').equalTo('Maths')`, data is filtered and returned successfully.

Why does `subjectref.orderByChild('department').equalTo(currentworker.department)` not work?

Comment: Given what you describe, it seems that `currentworker.department` is not returning `'Maths'`. I'd put a breakpoint on that line, and run to it in a debugger to determine what it *does* return and why that is.

Comment: Hello, I did that. and everything seems to be okay. I printed ```currentworker.department``` in debug console too and it does returns the logged in user's department. Not sure why the query wonn't.

Comment: If `currentworker.department` returns`'Maths'`, then the two pieces of code should behave exactly the same. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the code that logs that value, and its output?

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/r2riuu/firebaseanimatedlist_query_returns_a_blank_list/